# Change BackColor of button when focus in Window Form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, focus

I need to change button BackColor on focus. 
Now I am using `MouseOverBackColor`<=**Silver** in a button.
When I focus the button by mouse, its backcolor changed to **Silver**.
When I focus the button by tab key or `.focus()` from code behind,I want to change the backcolor of it to **Silver**.
Which event should I use?
Can anybody help me,please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus`, or the `Enter` and `Leave` events for this purpose.

```
private void myBtn_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBtn.BackColor = Color.Silver;
}

private void myBtn_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBtn.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep consistency, you may have both `tab` and `mouseover` to change the button colour when focus is on the Form.

But you need to override low level Got, LostFocus events.

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
}

protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355140/cant-find-gotfocus-lostfocus-in-my-user-control)

- You may also try [enter and leave events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)